# code coverage in else

Tags: unit-test

else if line is getting covered and is shown in blue/green, but the next two lines are in red. How to get that covered?

```
} else if ((checkedSummaryPlanIds == totalSummaryPlanIds) && (planIdMatch == false)) {
      skippedRecords += ddRecs.Plan_id__c + ' - ' + ddRecs.account_name__c + '\n'; // concatinated list of skipped records plan ids
      totalSkippedCtr++;
}
```

Comment: The short version is that you need to specifically set up your test so that you don't hit the initial IF statment, but do satisfy this ELSE IF. Generally, you should have one test method per branch (one that covers the IF, a separate test that covers the ELSE IF, yet another test that covers the ELSE)

Comment: else if seems covered and that line is in green/blue.. but not sure why not the rest of the code below it...

Comment: that'd be because you're evaluating the else if's expression, but the result is false so you do not enter into the else if block